# Using parameter expansion to generate arguments list for `mkdir -p`

Tags: zsh

I have something like this:

```
% ls -1dF /tmp/foo/*
/tmp/foo/000f9e956feab3ee4625aebb65ae7bae9533cdbc/
/tmp/foo/002e34c2218f2c86fefd2876f0e5c2559c5fb3c4/
/tmp/foo/00b483576791bab751e6cb7ee0a7143af43a8069/
.
.
.
/tmp/foo/fedd0f7b545e7ae9600142656756456bc16874d3/
/tmp/foo/ff51ac87609012137cfcb02f36624f81cdc10788/
/tmp/foo/ff8b983a7411395344cad64182cb17e7cdefa55e/
```

I want to create a directory `bar` under each of the subdirectories under `foo`.

If I try to do this with

```
% mkdir -p /tmp/foo/*/bar
```

...I get the error

```
zsh: no matches found: /tmp/foo/*/bar
```

(In hindsight, I can understand the reason for the error.)

I know that I can solve the original problem with a for-loop, but I'm curious to know if `zsh` supports some form of parameter expansion that would produce the desired argument for a single invocation of `mkdir -p`.  IOW, a parameter expansion equivalent to "append `/bar` to every prefix generated by expanding `/tmp/foo/*`", resulting in

```
% mkdir -p /tmp/foo/000f9e956feab3ee4625aebb65ae7bae9533cdbc/bar ... /tmp/foo/ff8b983a7411395344cad64182cb17e7cdefa55e/bar
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
setopt histsubstpattern extendedglob
mkdir -p /tmp/foo/*(#q/:s_%_/bar_)
```

This is *extended globbing* that has a `q`uiet *glob flag* that uses a *glob qualifier* to match only directories and a *modifier* to perform a `s`ubstitution (using the `%` pattern character that is only available in *history substitution pattern* mode) that appends a string to each word.

```
man zshexpn
```

Comment: Wow, I'm impressed.  I even found it all in the man page you specify.

Comment: Note that the Original Poster specified `mkdir -p`, which would have the slightly different effect from your command of not throwing errors if some of those directories already have `bar` subdirectories.  Minor point but worth noting here.  :)

Comment: Another way is to use array expansion via [`${^spec}`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html) and append `bar` to each element of whatever `/tmp/foo/*(/)` expands to:  `set -- /tmp/foo/*(/)` then `mkdir -p -- "${^@}/bar"`

Answer (score 5):

Sure - use a loop

```
for n in /tmp/foo/*; do mkdir "$n/bar";done
```

globs are used to expand lists of *existing* items, not things which have not yet been created.

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid my question was not clearly stated.  I will clarify it.

Comment: This doesn't answer if `zsh` can expand globs and append text with a single syntax—but I do think it's likely the only way to do what you want, @kjo.

Answer (score 4):

If the directories are in an array, you can use the `${^...}` form of expansion.

```
a=(/tmp/foo/*/)
mkdir -p ${^a}bar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` and `xargs` to do it:

```
find /tmp/foo -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | xargs -i echo mkdir -p {}/bar
```

which uses `-maxdepth 1` and `-mindepth 1` to prevent creation of `bar` in subdirectories of targets, and in `/tmp/foo` itself respectively. `type d` makes it consider directories only.

You have to remove `echo` to perform actual actions, otherwise `echo` will only print out lines to execute. You can also enclose it in substitution like `$()` to execute it.

Manual says `xargs -i` is deprecated, but I found no other equally handy alternative, so it should still work for some years...
You can replace `-i` with `-I'{}'` to be up-to-date with that.

Comment: This answer and the next one look good to me. Can someone explain why they should be down voted?  Down votes are fine, but how can we learn if no reasons are given?

Comment: It is a working alternative doing nothing but what OP asked. Beats me.

Comment: I think it's some kind of bias that answers must have bad answers on them, so prejudice took it's toll on my reputation.

Comment: I don't like unexplained down votes, but I haven't seen any such bias. Usually, "bad" answers (the ones that I understand) are actually bad.

Answer (score 0):

@loa_in_ had most of it, but piping `find` output tends to be a faux pas.

```
find /tmp/foo -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec mkdir {}/bar \;
```

Comment: I just use `xargs` with different tools which don't have `-exec` alternative, so I use my approach as it works with all of them equally.